# Can't see Power view thumbnails in SharePoint gallery

Tags: powerview

Created a Power view chart in Excel 2013 and uploaded it to the gallery. The file uploaded ok, but I can't see the data on my charts (unless I open it in excel).

Otherwise I get a message:

> Unsupported Features There are some features in your workbook that we can't show in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected behaviour of the Sharepoint BI. Below are the useful articles related to this issue

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2990993
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7396.sharepoint-2010-powerpivot-gallery-thumbnailssnapshots-not-rendering.aspx